# How to use Perl's LWP::UserAgent GET request with tsocks

Tags: perl, tsocks

I can connect to a remote url using the proxy from tsocks in the following way:

```
tsocks telnet host port
```

How can I do the same using the Perl's `LWP::UserAgent` module?
I've been so far trying it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.16;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Data::Dumper;

#my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 10,
    ssl_opts => {
        #verify_hostname => 0,
        verify_hostname => 0,
        SSL_verify_mode => '0x01',
        SSL_version     => 'SSLv23:!SSLv3:!SSLv2',
    }
);
$ua->proxy(['http', 'https' ], 'https://proxy_host:proxy_port' );

my $request = GET ( 'https://remote_url', Accept => 'application/json' );
$request->authorization_basic( 'username', 'password' );
say $request->as_string();

my $response = $ua->request( $request );
say $response->as_string();
```

By the way, I don't have socks installed on this server. So I'll need to do it without them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## LWP::UserAgent and SOCKS

You may use [`LWP::Protocol::socks`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::socks) perl package make [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent)  [`SOCKS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) capable.

IMHO it is much better way for your own perl scripts.
`tsocks` may be better for legacy perl scripts you do not want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which might be very specific for my case:

Before running the script, I just call `tsocks` like this:

```
tsocks script_name.pl
```